# Installing Shibboleth on Windows server quits with USERS is not a valid user or group

Tags: windows-server, shibboleth-sp

I was installing Shibboleth Service Provider on a server and it did not work. In the Windows event log, I got the error

> Product: Shibboleth Service Provider -- Error 1609. An error occurred while applying    security settings. USERS is not a valid user or group. This could be a problem with the package, or a problem connecting to a domain controller on the network. Check your network connection and click Retry, or Cancel to end the install. Unable to locate the user's SID, system error 1332

I searched the internet and was informed, it might help to create a local user group `USERS` on the server.
I wonder if this is a known issue with Shibboleth on a Windows server in German language.
How do I install Shibboleth SP?

[image]